# How can I convert an SDWebImage to a UIImage?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, sdwebimage

I need to convert an image I downloaded from Firebase using SDWebImage to a UIImage. How can I do this? Here is my code so far:

```
Database.database().reference().child("movies").child(movieNumString).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
    if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
        let UrlString: String? = ((dictionary["posterPhotoURL"] as? String))
        let Url = URL(string: (UrlString)!)

        self.moviePosterImageView.sd_setImage(with: Url, placeholderImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "PImage"))
}
```

Comment: Use the method with the `completed` closure that should have an `UIImage` as a property (check the `SDExternalCompletionBlock`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this callBack method

```
self.moviePosterImageView.sd_setImage(with:Url,
               placeholderImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "PImage"), 
               options: [],
               completed: { (image, error,cacheType, url) in
        // here image is the UIImage    

    self.moviePosterImageView.image = image?.roundedWithBorder(width: 2, color: .red)   
})
```

Comment: self.moviePosterImageView.sd_setImage(with: Url, placeholderImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "PImage"), options: [], completed: { (image, error,cacheType, url) in
                                            image?.roundedWithBorder(width: 0, color: .red)
                                        })

Comment: But image?.roundedWithBorder(width: 0, color: .red) is not used (sorry for the bad formatting, I am new to SO).

Comment: if `roundedWithBorder ` is an extension to **UIImageView** , then use `self.moviePosterImageView.round.....` , also change width to any value as border with width = 0 won't even appear

Comment: @Sh_Kahn It is an extension of UIImage

Comment: if you meant to graphically change it , then reassign it see edit